# SQL... How to update rows with data from other rows in the same table?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm using MySQL server and I have a table where some rows are missing data.  I would like to update the rows using information from other rows.  My table looks something like:

```
id,signin,deviceId,deviceModel
1,2010-10-12,9ABC9,
2,2010-10-12,3E44F,
3,2010-10-13,D3453,
4,2010-10-14,D3453,
5,2010-10-14,D3453,HW1
6,2010-10-12,3E44F,HW2
7,2010-10-12,9ABC9,HW1
```

For the first few entries, the deviceModel field is empty.  I would like to update this value using the deviceModel found for the deviceId in other rows of this same table. In the example above, row 1 should have deviceModel = HW1, row 2 should have deviceModel = HW2, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this is a denormalised design. You should move deviceModel -> deviceId relation to another table.

Second:

```
UPDATE
  yourTable AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    deviceId, deviceModel 
  FROM 
    yourTable 
  WHERE 
    deviceModel IS NOT NULL
) AS t2
USING (deviceId)
SET
  t1.deviceModel = t2.deviceModel
WHERE
  t1.deviceModel IS NULL
```

Comment: You're right, this is the way I should build the table.  Let me see if I can break it up and try this method.

Answer (score 2):

[Self Join](http://databases.about.com/od/sql/a/selfjoins.htm)  -

```
UPDATE MyTable m1, MyTable m2 
SET m1.deviceModel= m2.deviceModel
WHERE m1.deviceid=m2.deviceid and m2.deviceModel is not null
```

Comment: Invalid SQL. There's no FROM in UPDATEs

Comment: My MySQL believes otherwise: `SQL synax error near 'from` . Not to mention the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html Your second query however seems fine.

Comment: My bad..didnt see it was MySQL updated it thanks for your correction.

Comment: No problem. Which SQL flavor has FROM in UPDATE BTW?

Comment: Thanks... Now I just have to figure out why my connection is timing out.  I get "Query execution was interrupted."  There are only 13000 rows and only about 25% need updating.